# Operator Sdk query regarding fetching an instance from k8 cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

```
memcached := &cachev1alpha1.Memcached{} 
err := r.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, memcached)
```

in the above code are we making an empty object of the struct Memcached then getting this instance from the kubernetes cluster.

if this is an empty instance then i saw an example where someone used this instance and assigned values like (scaler is the instance which as start,end , replicas as its struct members)

```
startTime := scaler.spec.start
endTime := scaler.spec.end
Replicas := scaler.spec.replicas
```

How can we fetch from empty instance , start ,end replicas by defualt will have some values like 0 or 1 or empty string.

i am a newbie kindly take this in consideration.

i was expecting that before .get we are creating an empty object then fetch that object from k8.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by empty instance?

Comment: Memcached{}  this syntax makes object by its default values